# iPhone SDK: How can I get mic volume?

Tags: iphone

I want to get the volume or even how much noise is coming through the mic.

So, if someone is talking or some noise is going on in the background, I want to know how much.

Which framework should I use: `AudioToolbox`, `AudioUnit`, `AVFoundation` or `CoreAudio`?

Comment: Is this for an app that secretly autorecords conversations?

Comment: No. There are apps that respond to noise coming through the mic( Ocarina, MouthOFF ) and I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: Do you know how to get mic volume? I'm trying to do the same.